# Modeling pedigree properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating an app to represent the pedigree of livestock. Each child has one dam (e.g. ewe) and one sire (e.g. ram). A dam/sire pairing can have multiple children (e.g. lambs) and a dam and sire may have many more children independent of the other. I am trying to represent this relationship so that I could do something like `ewe.children` and get a listing of her offspring. Similarly, I'd like to be able to do something like `lamb.ewe` to get her mother or `lamb.ewe.ewe` to get her maternal grandmother.

from `schema.rb`...

```
create_table "parent_child_relationships", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "parent_id"
  t.integer "child_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["child_id"], name: "index_parent_child_relationships_on_child_id"
  t.index ["parent_id", "child_id"], name: "index_parent_child_relationships_on_parent_id_and_child_id", unique: true
  t.index ["parent_id"], name: "index_parent_child_relationships_on_parent_id"
end
```

from `parent_child_relationship.rb`...

```
class ParentChildRelationship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sire, class_name: "Animal"
  belongs_to :dam, class_name: "Animal"
  belongs_to :children, class_name: "Animal"
end
```

from `animal.rb`...

```
has_one :sire_relationship, class_name:  "ParentChildRelationship",
                        foreign_key: "child_id",
                    dependent:   :destroy
has_one :dam_relationship, class_name:  "ParentChildRelationship",
                        foreign_key: "child_id",
                    dependent:   :destroy
has_many :child_relationships, class_name:  "ParentChildRelationship",
                        foreign_key: "parent_id",
                    dependent:   :destroy

has_one :sire, through: :sire_relationship, source: :child
has_one :dam, through: :dam_relationship, source: :child
has_many :children, through: :child_relationships, source: :parent
```

In the console, I run the following commands to grab the animals I want to relate to each other...

```
s = Shepherd.first
ewe = s.animals.find_by(id: 37)
ram = s.animals.find_by(id: 133)
lamb = s.animals.find_by(id: 61)
```

Now, when I try to create the `sire_relationship` and `dam_relationship` I get an error since it doesn't seem to see the relationship as being unique. The `sire_relationship` is replaced by the `dam_relationship`...

```
>> lamb.create_sire_relationship(parent_id: ram.id)
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "parent_child_relationships" ("parent_id", "child_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["parent_id", 133], ["child_id", 61], ["created_at", "2018-01-15 15:33:06.649936"], ["updated_at", "2018-01-15 15:33:06.649936"]]
   (2.5ms)  commit transaction
  ParentChildRelationship Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "parent_child_relationships".* FROM "parent_child_relationships" WHERE "parent_child_relationships"."child_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["child_id", 61], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<ParentChildRelationship id: 1, parent_id: 133, child_id: 61, created_at: "2018-01-15 15:33:06", updated_at: "2018-01-15 15:33:06">
>> lamb.create_dam_relationship(parent_id: ewe.id)
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "parent_child_relationships" ("parent_id", "child_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["parent_id", 37], ["child_id", 61], ["created_at", "2018-01-15 15:33:35.045703"], ["updated_at", "2018-01-15 15:33:35.045703"]]
   (1.0ms)  commit transaction
  ParentChildRelationship Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "parent_child_relationships".* FROM "parent_child_relationships" WHERE "parent_child_relationships"."child_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["child_id", 61], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  DELETE FROM "parent_child_relationships" WHERE "parent_child_relationships"."id" = ?  [["id", 1]]
   (1.2ms)  commit transaction
=> #<ParentChildRelationship id: 2, parent_id: 37, child_id: 61, created_at: "2018-01-15 15:33:35", updated_at: "2018-01-15 15:33:35">
```

Creating the `children_relationships`, I get these errors...

```
>> ewe.child_relationships.create(child_id: lamb.id)
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "parent_child_relationships" ("parent_id", "child_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["parent_id", 37], ["child_id", 61], ["created_at", "2018-01-15 15:37:11.436086"], ["updated_at", "2018-01-15 15:37:11.436086"]]
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: parent_child_relationships.parent_id, parent_child_relationships.child_id: INSERT INTO "parent_child_relationships" ("parent_id", "child_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    from (irb):13
>> ram.child_relationships.create(child_id: lamb.id)
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "parent_child_relationships" ("parent_id", "child_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["parent_id", 133], ["child_id", 61], ["created_at", "2018-01-15 15:37:25.264947"], ["updated_at", "2018-01-15 15:37:25.264947"]]
   (2.5ms)  commit transaction
```

Finally, if I check to see whether I can access the `sire` of `lamb`, I get another error...

```
>> lamb.dam
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) :child in model ParentChildRelationship. Try 'has_many :dam, :through => :dam_relationship, :source => <name>'. Is it one of sire, dam, or children?
    from (irb):21
>> lamb.sire
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) :child in model ParentChildRelationship. Try 'has_many :sire, :through => :sire_relationship, :source => <name>'. Is it one of sire, dam, or children?
    from (irb):22
```

I get similar errors if I do `ewe.children` or `ram.children`.

I'm looking for an extra pair of eyes to tell me what I'm doing wrong or whether there's an easier way to achieve what I'm after.

Comment: I think your `ParentChildRelationship` class is flawed/unnecessary (the `children` attribute should be named `child`?). Might as well store the `sire_id` and `dam_id` directly in the Animal class. Unless you want to store lots of extra information in the link table.

Comment: I'm not sure that helps me do what I want. If I store the sire/dam ids in the Animal class, it's not as easy to get all of a dam's children. Also, it gets pretty cumbersome to get an animals great grand parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you only have one `parent_id` in your animals table which can only store the ID of a single parent. This works for bacteria but not for animals which have two parents. Your `parent_id` is getting written to when you set the dam and the sire.

There are multiple ways to do this but I think the simplest is to have a `dam_id` and `sire_id` in your animals table.

This is the migration to create the table:

```
class CreateAnimals < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :animals do |t|
      t.integer :dam_id, index: true
      t.integer :sire_id, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

This is what your model will look like this. Notice that you need two `belongs_to`/`has_many` relationships:

```
class Animal < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :dam, class_name: 'Animal'
  belongs_to :sire, class_name: 'Animal'

  has_many :children_as_sire, class_name: 'Animal', foreign_key: :sire_id
  has_many :children_as_dam, class_name: 'Animal', foreign_key: :dam_id

  def children
    children_as_dam + children_as_sire
  end
end
```

Notice the getter method `children` that grabs both `children_as_dam` and `children_as_sire`. This will result in two SQL queries which is not ideal. If you're tracking the sec of the Animal, you could do something like:

```
def children?
  case sex
  when 'male'
    children_as_sire
  when 'female'
    children_as_dam
  end
end
```

I wrote some specs to demonstrate:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Animal, type: :model, focus: true do
  it 'can be created' do
    expect { Animal.create }.to_not raise_error
  end

  it 'can have a dam' do
    animal = Animal.new
    animal.update! dam: Animal.create
    expect(animal.dam).to be_a(Animal)
    expect(animal.sire).to be_nil
  end

  it 'can have a sire' do
    animal = Animal.new
    animal.update! sire: Animal.create
    expect(animal.sire).to be_a(Animal)
    expect(animal.dam).to be_nil
  end

  it 'can have both a dam and a sire and tell the difference' do
    dam = Animal.create
    sire = Animal.create
    child = Animal.create dam: dam, sire: sire

    expect(child.reload.dam).to eq(dam)
    expect(child.reload.sire).to eq(sire)
  end

  it 'grandma' do
    grandma = Animal.create
    dam = Animal.create dam: grandma
    child = Animal.create dam: dam

    expect(child.reload.dam.dam).to eq(grandma)
  end

  it 'has children' do
    sire = Animal.create
    animal = Animal.create sire: sire
    expect(sire.reload.children).to include(animal)
  end
end
```

Notice that you can't add children to a model:

```
animal = Animal.create

animal.children << Animal.create # will raise an error
```

Instead, you have to manually set the sire and dam (which is probably what you want to do since you're keeping track).